# How to wrap a zeromq bind socket in a twisted application service?

Tags: python, twisted, zeromq

I am using `txzmq` and `twisted` to build a listener service that will process some data through a push-pull pattern. Here's a working code:

```
from txzmq import ZmqFactory, ZmqEndpoint, ZmqPullConnection
from twisted.internet import reactor

zf = ZmqFactory()
endpoint = ZmqEndpoint('bind', 'tcp://*:5050')

def onPull(data):
    # do something with data

puller = ZmqPullConnection(zf, endpoint)
puller.onPull = onPull

reactor.run()
```

My question is - how can I wrap this code in a twisted application service? That is, how to wrap this into a specific service (e.g. `MyService`) that I can later run with:

```
from twisted.application.service import Application

application = Application('My listener')
service = MyService(bind_address='*', port=5050)
service.setServiceParent(application)
```

with the `twistd` runner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IService](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.application.service.IService.html) defines what it means to be a service.  [Service](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.application.service.Service.html) is a base class that is often helpful when implementing a new service.

Just move your ZMQ initialization code into a `startService` method of an object that implements `IService`, perhaps a subclass of `Service`.  If you want to do proper cleanup too, then add some cleanup code to the `stopService` method of that class.